# Is there a multithreading in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: multithreading, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, parallel-processing

Now I run data transformations sequentially in my PL/SQL ETL scripts.

I've noticed that some transformations do not depend on each other. 
Is there a way to open a thread in PL/SQL and offload some of the processing so job finishes faster?

I tried some performance options including setting parallelism degree but it's capped for a session.

I cannot use Java and I cannot design jobs outside Oracle - it has to be PL/SQL.

Comment: You could use the `dbms_job` or `dbms_scheduler` package.  I would expect that you'd want to use the newer `dbms_scheduler` and architect your entire ELT process as a job chain.  Without more information, though, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: @JustinCave Any examples?

Comment: Do a Google search for `dbms_scheduler` and you'll get thousands of hits.

Comment: Like I said, without more information, it's very hard to give you any sort of specifics.  The first page of Google results has plenty of implementation examples.  https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g is one of the first links, for example.  As is http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_SCHEDULER.  If those aren't the examples you are looking for, please help us better understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: As I said you have bunch of DMLs in your code and they do not depend on each other. Can I run them in threads in parallel in PL/SQL? Any sources?

Comment: The simplest possible approach would be to use the old, despported `dbms_job` package and just do a `dbms_job.submit` with the DML you want to run in a separate session.  The preferred approach would be to set up one or more jobs using `dbms_scheduler` and to set up a chain to run them with whatever dependencies you want.

Comment: The two links I copied earlier, the Oracle documentation that pops up on the first page of Google results, and the rest of the top page of results has a ton of different examples.  If those examples aren't what you are looking for, it would be helpful to explain what you've tried and why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: It's like pointing to Python's multithreading module. I know it's there, but not very helpful.

Comment: Let's take the first link I provided (oracle-base).  The first example is a call to `dbms_scheduler.create_job`.  That may be sufficient for you.  Or it might be too basic for your real needs.  Maybe you want to define a program and call that program.  Maybe you want to go all the way to defining a job chain with various dependencies https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-enhancements-10gr2#job_chains  I don't know enough about what you are trying to accomplish to do much more than point you at documentation about your options.

Answer (score 3):

If you tried "parallelism degree" setting, I think it's possible to run some of your ETL operations in parallel, so you will have a "task" which will wait it's child threads, each of these threads will process only it's "chunk" (subset of all records). In Oracle since 11g Release 2 there is a package DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE which manages it. I've got simple example.

Preparing test data:

```
create table test_parallel_processing(
    col_id int
  , col    number
)

begin
  for i in 1..1000 loop
    execute immediate 'insert into test_parallel_processing 
                            select :p1, 100 from dual' using i;
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```

Process all 1000 records in 4 chunks with parallel degree of 2:

```
declare
  v_sql          varchar2(1000);
  v_chunking_sql varchar2(1000);
begin
  /*we can use our own logic of deviding all scope to chunks:*/
  v_chunking_sql := ' select 1 as start_id, 250 as end_id from dual
                        union all
                      select 251 as start_id, 500 as end_id from dual
                        union all
                      select 501 as start_id, 750 as end_id from dual
                        union all
                      select 751 as start_id, 1000 as end_id from dual';

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_TASK ('mytask');
  /*creating chunks with our sql*/
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL(
      task_name => 'mytask'
    , sql_stmt  => v_chunking_sql
    , by_rowid  => false
  ); 

  /*SQL which will be performed in each chunk*/
  v_sql := 'update test_parallel_processing 
               set col = col*2
             where col_id between :start_id and :end_id';

  /*running task with any parallel degree, for example, 2*/
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK('mytask', v_sql, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                 parallel_level => 2);
  /*I comment this, cause dropping task will also delete information 
    about task and chunks from views:     USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS
                                     and  USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS*/
  --DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task ('mytask');                                  
end;
```

You can control state and result of processing using views:

```
USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS
USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS
```

Comment: Great tool, but my DBA refuses to install DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE citing security concerns and problems with RAC.

Comment: @biengineer you can select USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS or, if you have rights, DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS by your 'task_name'. In the field 'status' will be 'PROCESSING', 'FINISHED', 'FINISHED_WITH_ERROR' or several other statuses. In case of errors you can check exact sql error code in views USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS (DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS).